# post request via cURL ssl from xampp (localhost) gets rejected with error:14094410:SSL

Tags: ssl, curl

As the title suggests I'm trying to send a Post request using a token granted via oauth2, The problem is that the request is rejected by the server and the error code is

OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

My code:

```
$url = "https://webserviceapl.anaf.ro/test/FCTEL/rest/upload?standard=UBL&cif=18220220";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: Bearer /*my token here*/",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Content-Length: 0",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($err);
var_dump($resp);
```

I tried disabling ssl verification that resulted with the same error.

I have the impression that the server wants me to present something other than the bearer token, like

```
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $caFile);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);
```

But I have no idea from where to get a valid certificate.

The bearer token (if that is what I got) was granted to me via Postman App.
The flow was:
Registration with username/password, got a user id/secret, setup auth url, callback url, token url, made the request from postman, the server gave me a code which i exchanged for the token. At the exchange moment the server asked for a certificate stored on a thumb drive. I entered the thumbs password and received the token. The thumb itself it's enrolled in their system for my comapny.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated

Open ssl flags a problem with self signed certificate on my side and with No client certificate CA names sent.
It points to the same error that my code gets, meaning: 50370000:error:0A000410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 40

```
C:\Users\77BBA>openssl s_client -showcerts -servername webserviceapl.anaf.ro -connect webserviceapl.anaf.ro:443
CONNECTED(000001AC)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify error:num=19:self-signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "DigiCert, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.anaf.ro
verify return:1
50370000:error:0A000410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 40
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.anaf.ro
   i:C = US, O = "DigiCert, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep 16 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 16 23:59:59 2023 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = "DigiCert, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: May  4 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Nov  9 23:59:59 2031 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA1
   v:NotBefore: Nov 10 00:00:00 2006 GMT; NotAfter: Nov 10 00:00:00 2031 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN = *.anaf.ro
issuer=C = US, O = "DigiCert, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4876 bytes and written 465 bytes
Verification error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: A9F5C347ED68A6DA711C963E34102EC0923BB3B6B5546A35C8C2801DC5603F92
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 902B17A4EE2A1806BC8238AF23E4B0B1F7F70A5C38E11B81124BCBC444834A8C2BD5B944F243970551A522D1213532E3
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1666949305
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the impression that the server wants me to present something other than the bearer token, like

Correct. The server wants a client certificate and complains if none is provided. This can be seen when using curl:

```
...
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
...
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

> But I have no idea from where to get a valid certificate.

What client certificate is expected depends on the requirements of the server.  It does not seem to accept some random certificate. This is similar to the server expecting any other form of authentication, it will not accept some random username and password either.

So if you want to access the server you have to check with the server providers or their documentation of what certificate you actually need and how to get it.

Comment: While this is the romanian equivalent of the us irs they have a joke of the api and zero practical examples of how to implement it. They only provide examples from apps and browses extension ( postman for the token and restman/chrome for requests). While following their examples everything is working a ok, but both restman and postman appeal to the phisical pcke (thumb drive) that has the signed certificate on it. My problem is that  xampp server that runs the code does not request that thumb drive on its own like chrome does, i have no ideea what code to write to acces it during handshake...

Answer (score 0):

maybe a qualified certificate from fiscal authorities is required

Answer (score 0):

The `https://webserviceapl.anaf.ro` URL is for web browser access with qualified digital signature. For API calls with OAuth2 the correct URL is `https://api.anaf.ro`.

The ANAF documentation is a huge mess, wasted 2 hours querying the wrong endpoint.